# How to get intermediate feedback from my REST service for a single GET request

Tags: web-services, jquery, rest, angularjs, jersey

In my user interface, I am trying to implement a progress bar which shows the percent of completion of work for a user request.

My back-end REST service needs to do a lot of computations; hence it is relatively slow. I want to show the user what work in backend is finished. For instance: Task1 finished, working on Task2 (hence show 50% on the progress bar)

**My problem:**

The service returns result only after it has finished its entire task. I do not know how to get intermediate feedback to show the user that a certain percent of work is complete so he/she should be patient.

**Just to clarify, before you start suggesting any of following:**

1. I do not want to use gif Ajax loader.
2. Service is already optimized, cannot be fine tuned any further.
3. The service work is already very atomic, it cannot be further broken down in more than 1 service without causing further performance penalty due to additional network traffic.

Let me know if above is not possible to accomplish, I can stop my search.

Comment: getting intermeidate feedback from webserver would be very difficult so im afraid you could just depend upon approximation you can use $timeout to increase the progress of progress bar in specific time interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is bi-directional communication with an HTTP-Server and there are basically two ways to do it:

- **Rest-Polling**:
  Set up a second API-Call that a client could poll in regular intervals to get the current status of the computation.
- **WebSockets**:
  Set up a WebSocket-connection between your client and your server, which would allow the server to initiate the communication to the client and send a message as soon as a task is finished. Adding WebSockets just for that would probably cause even more network traffic than Rest-Polling.

If none of these are options for you, then I don`t think that what you want is possible.

Comment: +1 for Rest-Polling. This seems like the most appropriate answer given the question as described. Also, easier to implement.